# Google App Engine - Flask - SQLAlchemy - Inconsistent Database

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy

On my local server the application database runs fine and always brings up the same results but when I deploy my Flask application to the server and I add an item the results vary when I retrieve the data. You can view this problem on http://rest-menuapp.appspot.com/JSON. If you refresh the page you will see that sometimes the item is not there and sometimes it is there.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT item_catalog:app
threadsafe: false
runtime_config:
  python_version: 2

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /static/photos
  static_dir: static/photos

- url: /.*
  script: item_catalog.app
```

Here is my database

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///catalog.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

This is the start of my routing python file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, jsonify,\
     url_for, session, g, send_from_directory
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, asc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from PIL import Image
import os



from apiclient import discovery
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client, crypt

from database import init_db, db_session
from models import Item, Category, User, Photo

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/photos'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
init_db()


app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: You're storing state locally in a file. If you have multiple instances running your app, you'll have multiple copies of your data, each different from the others.

Comment: This is the catalog.db. How would I change to save it for all instances.

Comment: Would I just need to setup a postgresql database? Or how can i turn off multiple instances?

Comment: I'd recommend using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

So the quick and easy solution to this was to change my google app engine to only use one instance. This was done by adding:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

to my app.yaml file.

As univerio mentioned in the comments I was storing the database file locally and as there were multiple instances there would be multiple versions of the database. Another solution to this would be to switch my database to PostgreSQL. For my purposes simply limiting the amount of instances was a good enough solution.